# can't make simple typeahead example work

Tags: typeahead.js

I have been struggling with typeahead, and I can't make a very simple example work. I Just want to start with the example given in documentation using states, but no joy. Here is what I am trying:

```
 <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg typeahead">
    </div>

</div>


<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/typeahead.js"></script>
<script>
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'States',
        local: ["Alabama","Alaska","West Virginia","Wisconsin","Wyoming"]
    });
</script>
```

Using jquery 1.11, bootstrap 3.2.  Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: What version of typeahead are you using? The latest requires jquery 1.9+

Answer (score 1):

You've not specified a dataset for your typeahead call (i.e. the `source` parameter). Per the docs:

> `source` - The backing data source for suggestions. Expected to be a
>   function with the signature (query, cb). It is expected that the
>   function will compute the suggestion set (i.e. an array of JavaScript
>   objects) for query and then invoke cb with said set. cb can be invoked
>   synchronously or asynchronously.

See https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets

Comment: Thanks, yes I eventually found the documentation and got it working.